# How to exclude a custom constructor in webpack treeshaking?

Tags: javascript, webpack, constructor, tree-shaking

I have the following code in a JS file

```
(() => {
    const Abc = (ab) => {
        this.ab = ab;
        this.k = () => {
            console.log(this.ab);
        };
    };
    window.MySpace = window.MySpace || {};
    window.MySpace.abc = new Abc('some var');
})();
```

I'm using webpack 5 as my bundler. In another file that loads after this constructor, when I tried using `window.Myspace.abc.k`, it threw an error. With a little investigation, I'm able to understand that the output file does not have the `k`, as a result of `TreeShaking` mechanism.

How do I tell webpack to exclude this constructor/method during treeshaking?

Comment: You shouldn’t be able to use `new` on an arrow function like this in the first place…!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
window.MySpace.abc = new Abc('some var');
```

Abc is an arrow function. Arrow functions cannot be used as a constructor, so this line of code is throwing an exception, and thus nothing gets assigned to window.MySpace.abc.

To fix this, use a regular function:

```
function Abc(ab) {
  this.ab = ab;
  this.k = () => {
    console.log(this.ab);
  };
};
```